# UICollectionView and UITableView reload causes reorder of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I Have a situation where a thread got new models from the server, and I try to reload all cells in my `UICollectionViewController`.

I call `collectionView.reloadData()` (on main thread) and suddenly all the cells are changing their positions(meaning, I can see the content of the cells changing its position from one cell to another)

None Of the following works:

1. Sorting the data source to the same order
2. Saving the cells in custom dictionary, and rematch the data to the cells
3. `self.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths)` where indexPaths contain all current paths
4. reloading only visiable cells with `self.collectionView!.visibleCells()`

What am I missing here?

Comment: "I tried everything possible". What did you try? Where's your code? How can we possibly help you? Are we supposed to guess what you wrote?

Comment: @jcaron - if you can halp me and reopen this question - I will provide with a full and detailed answer, including all my findings , solution and an example

Answer (score 1):

If the server returned the right ordered data,I'm afraid you didn't clean up data in cells.You should set the imageView.image to nil when you hadn't loaded the image data or there was no image in the data.
If you customized your cell in UITableViewDataSource,you should do something like this：

```
if（data.image != nil) {
    imageView.image = data.image;
} else {
    imageView.image = nil;
}
```

If you did this in a custom table view cell class,do like this:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    imageView.image = nil 
}
```

Comment: Im a little bit lost here-
i have image,label and background color for each cell. when should i remove them?

Comment: @YoavR. Updated my answer.